# loaded content from external php not working with snap.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am using the Snap.js library (https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/) to create a dynamic side panel. This is my main content:

```
<!-- Central content -->


    <div id="content" class="snap-content">
        <div id="toolbar">
            <a href="#" id="open-left">Open panel</a>
        </div>    
        <div id="dynamic-content"></div>

    </div>
```

As you see, there is a dynamic-content. It is loaded with the following function:

```
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dynamic-content').load('content/index.php')}); 

  </script>
```

The panel is working and the content is loaded. The only problem is that the snap.js panel is not responding when I click on this "dynamic-content" div.

This is the content of the loaded index.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<object  type="image/svg+xml" class="img" data="svg/map.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

I would like to have this

```
 <div id="dynamic-content"></div>
```

working just like the

```
<div id="content" class="snap-content">
```

does.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.